# How to resolve vulnerability issue for javascript

Tags: javascript, security, xss

We have vulnerability scan and found plenty of issues related to following java script line. I tired it by googling and came to know that need to follow XSS Rules to avoid vulnerability issues in java script but didn't find best practice for the following line.Please can anybody help me how to mention same line to avoid vulnerability issue and not part of vulnerability scan

```
document.getElementById('demo1').style.display='none';
```

To avoid cross script attack/Vulnerability have done following thing,If i am wrong correct me

```
var elem = document.getElementById("demo1");
elem.style.display= 'none';
```

Comment: 1. There's no XSS vulnerability in the first code block. 2. If there were, it would also exist in the second code block.

Comment: This isn't XSS, but if you have inline JavaScript on your page (as opposed to in external .js files), you may have content security policy issues.

Comment: OK thanks for your quick response But one more question is there any tools or online sites to test vulnerability issues in our code.

Comment: Can you please post the whole report? It should state what the vulnerability is about.

Answer (score 2):

There is no potential vulnerability in the code you pasted XSS or other. Rewriting as you did doesn't change anything. I think you are looking at the wrong line which is very likely if you are using a javascript build system/transpiler/minifier/optimizer.

Comment: No FYI.. This is the line only and may be some times scan used to show which are not really issue.